# Testing if code executes in debug mode

Tags: vb.net, debugging

How can i test that the code executes in debug mode.

Here is what i would like to do in pseudocode

```
if not debugMode then
  Do something()
end if
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [Debugger.IsAttached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached(VS.71).aspx) to determine whether the program is being debugged.

```
If Not Debugger.IsAttached Then
  DoSomething()
End If
```

EDIT If you always want to skip the `DoSomething` code in the debug build, whether or not a debugger is being used, use [conditional compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/conditional-compilation) with [#If](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx6yas69.aspx), something like this

```
#IF DEBUG Then
  DoSomething()
#End If
```

Answer (score 10):

What do you mean with debug mode? If you refer to a debug build, you can use `#if DEBUG` to test for that:

```
#if DEBUG
    // this is included in a debug build
#else
    // this is not included in a debug build
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use IsDebuggerPresent Function

```
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling:=True)> _
Public Shared Function IsDebuggerPresent() As Boolean
End Function

if not isDebuggerPresent() then
Do something()
end if
```